# Physical Server Network Bridge caused serious issues across network (DNS, AD, Internet Connectivity)

Tags: networking, dns

Ok So yesterday I noticed that one of my spare servers within a small enterprise network had 4 network cards, which in turn had 4 IP addresses. We have planned to use this server for development purposes and we decided that we didn't want it to have 4 IP addresses. So we bridged the 4 network connections. Shortly afterwards we started noticing servers becoming unresponsive, most noticeable was one of the Virtual hosts. Then we realised that the affected servers were not longer authenticated on the network, it had seemed like the Domain controller were having DNS issues in the form of NETLOGON errors 5783. Active directory Domain Controller was unresponsive and therefore we could not add anything new clients into the network.

One of the most puzzling issues that was caused was the constant packet loss across the network. Internet connectivity was completely erratic, up-down-up-down. The domain controller and all of the effected servers would constantly lose connection during remote sessions making it almost impossible to troubleshoot the issue without physically plugging into the server itself, it was as if the switches were experiencing a broadcast storm which was crippling the network. But this wasn't reflected within the light displays on the switches themselves.

All of these issues were resolved when I deleted the network bridge, could anyone offer any sort of logical explanation? As I cannot link the issues myself.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have detonated a network bomb. [Bridging](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-bridging.html) interfaces creates a situation where the interfaces are forwarding packets, which means that all of the various broadcast protocols that are present on your network are being sent out each interface, being picked up by each interface, and forwarded again. This results in an exponential growth that will eventually, depending on the speed of the interfaces and the ability of your network to handle it, bring the entire network to it's knees.

What you likely wanted to do was to *[bond](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding)* those interfaces so that they appeared to be one